# Provisions for a UN security council expansion

Tags: united-nations, unsc

When the UN was started way back in 1945 did the charter provide for reforms or was it envisioning  itself as a long term *exclusive club*? Or were there some provisions to expand membership from time to time depending on some laid out rules for newly defined international relations and possible new accommodation among member countries?

In particular in order to accept new members into the UNSC fold what conditions are required, what consensus or voting majority is needed ?

The question assumes significance after France recently justified inclusion of Germany, Japan and  India to move away from historical positions.

Comment: also duplicated here https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/reform-of-united-nations-security-council   Sorry, good question, but already asked.

Comment: It does answer. The update seems to be that there is no update .. Status quo would prevail for some more time.

Comment: This question could show a bit more research. Have you looked up the UN charta and searched for such provisions?

Comment: [UN Charter 1945 San Francisco][1]; Membership open to all peace loving countries; 2) New membership is through GA duly whetted by SC etc..

  [1]: https://popp.undp.org/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/UNDP_POPP_DOCUMENT_LIBRARY/Public/Charter%20of%20the%20United%20Nations.pdf&action=default&utm_source=EN&utm_medium=GSR&utm_content=US_UNDP_PaidSearch_Brand_English&utm_campaign=CENTRAL&c_src=CENTRAL&c_src2=GSR&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIv8yi-OW9-wIVFjErCh1sMgwOEAAYASAAEgLyJfD_BwE